# How to make installed .exe show proper details with Inno Setup under Windows

Tags: inno-setup

I use Inno Setup to create a Windows installable .exe for a Java app. I have  properly defined `AppName`, `AppVersion` and others in the `.iss` file. The info appear in the installable .exe details.

The problem is that after installation, the new executable .exe in the app folder doesn't have the same details, but takes JDK details. JDK has been packaged as a runtime dependency as well. `File Description` and `Product Name` appear the same as those of JRE.

[image]

Comment: What are the executable .exe you are talking about?

Comment: The launchable one, the one that is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the directives in the Setup section. Those things that you are finding are   VersionInfoDescription and VersionInfoProductName.

You shoud put the below to your code.

```
[Setup]
...
VersionInfoDescription="Put here to show the File Description."
VersionInfoProductName="Put here to show the Product Name."
...
```